# Can I add a list of input values to be recognised instead of just the one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The code below works fine but I would like to know if I can add more values to equal true like this..

if (text_value.includes("north", "east", "south", "west" ) === true)

or something similar?
I'm terrible at JS so go easy on me, simple terms please.

```js
document.getElementById('myText').onkeydown = function() {
  var text_value = document.getElementById('myText').value;
  if (text_value.includes("north") === true) {
    document.getElementById('OutputText').innerHTML = "You head North.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('OutputText').innerHTML = "";
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" />
<div class="output" id="OutputText"></div>
```

Comment: `myText` is missing from your markup. Is that an `<input>`?

Comment: There are more things than testing an array here. Please look at this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rfu0odp5/

Comment: Yes Andy that was meant to be input.